# Running React Native App in Nox Player

Tags: android, react-native

Environment

> CPU: AMD Ryzen 1300x
>
> OS: Win10 64bit-Home

I want to run my react native app using nox player.

> react-native run-android

It compiled buy says "com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!"

So I run

> adb devices

I got "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Now I was wondering what adb I must add to the Path Variable?

Should I put the nox/bin or android/sdk/platform-tools?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` and `c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` both to your `PATH` for React Native and `adb` to work.

Comment: Jagjot Singh, are you developing react native using nox as your emulator?